# How to make svg react component imports from external module working with create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg, create-react-app

## Context

In order to make some code parts re-usable accross many react project, I have the following project structure:

1. `@foo/design`: Containing design stuff such as raw svg images
2. `@foo/ui`: A react library base on Create React App for common component
3. `@foo/project`: A final CRA project using `foo/ui`

### The library

The `foo/ui` library export some a component that import a svg image from `@foo/design`:

```js
// MyComponent.ts
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import {
  ReactComponent as Logo,
} from '@foo/design/static/img/logo.svg';

export const MyComponent: FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      Some stuff.
      <Logo />
    </div>
  );
};

export default null;
```

This component works flawlessly on the related Storybook instance of `@foo/ui` and is compiled using `tsc` like this:

```js
// MyComponent.js
import { jsx as _jsx, jsxs as _jsxs } from "react/jsx-runtime";
import { ReactComponent as Logo, } from '@foo/design/static/img/logo.svg';
export var Navbar = function () {
    return (_jsxs("div", { children: ["Some stuff.", _jsx(Logo, {}, void 0)] }, void 0));
};
export default null;
```

Here is also the related `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": [
    "src/samples",
    "src/**/*.stories.*",
    "src/**/*.test.*",
    "src/setupTests.js"
  ],
}
```

### The project import

On `@foo/project`, I added the `@foo/ui` dependency, installing the `@foo/design` package as well (required by `@foo/ui`).

I use my component that way:

```js
import { FC } from 'react';
import { MyComponent } from '@foo/ui'

const App: FC = () => {
  return (
    <MyComponent />
  );
}

export default App;
```

But this produces the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@foo/ui/lib/MyComponent.js
Attempted import error: 'ReactComponent' is not exported from '@foo/design/static/img/logo.svg' (imported as 'Logo').
```

However, if I copy/past the svg import line from `MyComponent.js` directly on my root app component:

```js
import { FC } from 'react';
import { ReactComponent as Logo, } from '@foo/design/static/img/logo.svg';

const App: FC = () => {
  return (
    <Logo />
  );
}

export default App;
```

This works and the svg appears as expected.

Here is also the CRA project related `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Why the `ReactComponent` CRA import is not working when it's done from my imported library? What is the simplest way to solve this problem as `@foo/ui` is only use internally?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the only workaround helped me in a similar situation -
define SVG component inline, using https://svg2jsx.com/ to prepare component.

So, in your case, you won't be able to use shared SVG's from `@foo/design` to create a wrapper component, but at least you'll be able to prepare the shared SVG components in `@foo/ui`.

Spent much time, solved it just recently, so can't explain what's the underlying issue is.

Comment: Indeed, this is more a hack than an answer, but thanks for the tip! I'll keep it for desperate situations. ;-)

Comment: @Soullivaneuh, just curious, did you find anything more "long term"\mature to share?